# Failing to populate a react form with data from Database despite having done everything as instructed

Tags: reactjs

I am failing to populate a react form with data from database using the set Method, but when I do console.log(res.data) I can see the data fetched successfully. I have followed all the tutorials exactly word by word but it is just not working. I am also getting the warning: "Line 24:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps". And "Line 24:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" My code is as below:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import UsersService from "../../services/UsersService";

const EditUser = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    UsersService.findUserById(id)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setUser(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const userUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    UsersService.updateUser(user)
      .then((res) => {
        navigate("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-header fs-3 text-center">Edit User</div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <form onSubmit={(e) => userUpdate(e)}>
                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <label className="form-label">ID</label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="text"
                      name="id"
                      id="id"
                      value={id}
                      disabled
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="username"
                      name="username"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={user.username}
                      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="password"
                      name="password"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={user.password}
                      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <button className="btn btn-primary col-md-12">Update</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditUser;
```

Comment: Let's address the warning first. As it says, add `id` to the dependency array, like so: `useEffect(() => { UsersService.findUserById(id) ... }, [id]);`. Does this solve the issue? Let me know if so, and I'll add an answer with explanation.

Comment: That doesnt solve the bug. I have done that before. Sorry the other second warning is: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

Comment: The warning about a controlled input changing to uncontrolled suggests that `res.data` may not have the expected structure or keys. Can you log `res.data` to the console and post the result here.

Comment: The console.log(res.data) is returning: 1,admin123,admin :with 1 as id, admin123 as password and admin as username.

Comment: Hmm, that seems ok. Could you possibly create a minimal example that I could run on my PC (maybe stick it up on GitHub), then I'd be happy to take a closer look.

Comment: https://github.com/omudzingwa/crud_backend_frontend.git

Comment: That's a dump of your entire project. Pls simplify so as to make it easy for me to reproduce the error. And pls provide instructions on how to run the project and find the error. If you say that the backend is returning the correct values, you can probably hardcode them into the appropriate place.

Comment: Can I just give you the frontend part and you can use any backend of your choice that will have only three fields in the database namely:  id,username,password.

Comment: You can use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server. Easy to set up to serve just the response your app is expecting.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. See link below and kindly check the README.MD file first i have added some few notes. https://github.com/omudzingwa/zest_frontend

Comment: I replied here: https://github.com/omudzingwa/zest_frontend/issues/1
Let's carry on chatting there for a while, then when we have the solution, I'll post an answer on SO.

Comment: Problem solved. Check: https://github.com/omudzingwa/zest_frontend/issues/1